# How to add new aspx page in asp.net 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a new ASP.Net 5 application as empty and tried to add the aspx page through add new item. but there is no options to add aspx page rather that we can have all other items like view, controller, class library.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlike ASP.NET 5 MVC, ASP.NET 5 Webforms hasn't been developed yet. When it does, sometime in 2016 you'll be able to use both MVC and WebForms in the same project like you did in ASP.net 4.

Answer (score 5):

Files ending in `.aspx` are part of the Web Forms framework. ASP.NET 5 does not support Web Forms at all, nor will it ever support Web Forms. If you want to create a Web Forms application using Visual Studio 2015, you should choose **Web Forms** from the **ASP.NET 4.6 Templates** instead.

Answer (score 2):

`ASP.Net 5` is like `ASP.Net MVC`, you cannot add `.aspx` page but `.cshtml` razor view into your `Views` folder.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 5 support both MVC and webfrom. We have choose web application templet with Web Form, MVC or API.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

[image]